# Problems with fonts in Photoshop (all the text is pixelated)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, pixel

I really don't understand what is going on and I'd love if someone could help me with that.

Whenever I type something the letters are just pixelated and weird. Some of them are just fine (like F and H) but all there others letters are just wrong.

I don't know if the problem is the font, because this occurs with all my fonts.

This happens only in Photoshop, Illustrator is completely fine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. There's nothing wrong here. The resolution is too low. You are zoomed in all the way to the pixel level. I can see the zoom level on your screen shot.  Create a new document, and choose something like A4 as the size, at 300ppi, and set a font size something like 14pt.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem you are creating tiny images. In your bottom screenshot your zoom level is 827% and your image is still not covering your entire screen.

Try creating an image from a preset like Print > A4 or Web > 1920x1080. Add a text with a font size of *at least* 20pt. (*Window* > *Character* will show you the text controls.) This should give you normal text. If it doesn't, there is some serious issue going on with your Photoshop install.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, this is happening with all the fonts and in Illustrator it is okay (as a vector design app). So I guess the problem could be the size/resolution of the document. Maybe in Image -> Image Size check the size and the resolution and see if it makes sense or not.

Another thing that could be the reason is Anti-Aliasing. But as I see in screenshots, the pixels are so big so I don't think that it could be the issue, But have a look.